# Do tensor products support cancellation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

If $A\otimes B\simeq A\otimes C$, is it true that $B\simeq C$? If not, under what conditions might this be true?

EDIT:

More specifically, I'm working on a problem where I have a field $K$ and an ideal $I\subseteq A$, where $A$ is an algebra over $K$. I also have that $I\otimes_K K\simeq A\otimes_K K$. I would like to conclude that $I=A$. Can I do this? (This seems like it has to be true.)

Comment: Wouldn't, say, $\mathbb{Z}_2 \otimes \mathbb{Z} \simeq \mathbb{Z}_2 \otimes \mathbb{Z}_4$?

Comment: OK, so I'm pretty bad with tensor products. What would the isomorphism be between those two? The specific case I'm looking at is where A and C are rings and B is an ideal in C. Can I say B = C now?

Comment: In general, given a divisible group $D$ and and a finite group $G$ one has that $D\otimes_\mathbb{Z}G=0$. So, for example $\mathbb{Q}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}S_5=0$. That said, neither of these are the zero group.

Comment: I don't really know, I just remember a bit about it from topology.  I think I got it mixed up with something else there.  I think $\mathbb{Z}_7 \otimes \mathbb{Z}_4 \simeq \mathbb{Z}_7 \otimes \mathbb{Z}_2$ might be a better example.  In that case, you can multiply the generator in the right group by 4 and divide the left by 4 to get $\mathbb{Z}_7\otimes 0$ right?

Comment: See my edit to the post for the specific question. Based on your answers, "cancellation" doesn't apply always, so I've added more information specific to the problem I'm working on.

Comment: Which ring is your tensor product over? K or A?

Comment: @Jack: It's over K

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $K$ be the field of rational numbers, $A=K[x]$ be the ring of polynomials with coefficients from $K$, and $I=(x)$ be the ideal of polynomials $f$ with $f(0)=0$.

As $A$-modules, $I \cong A \cong I \otimes_K K \cong A \otimes_K K$, but $I \neq A$.

One of course has cancellation up to isomorphism: if $M$ is an $A$-module, then $M \otimes_K K \cong M$ as $A$-modules, so if $I \otimes_K K \cong A \otimes_K K$, then $I \cong I \otimes_K K \cong A \otimes_K K \cong A$.

If $A$ is a finite dimensional algebra, then things are better:  if $I \otimes_K K \cong A \otimes_K K$ then both $I$ and $A$ have the same dimension as $K$-vector spaces, and since $I \leq A$ and $A$ is finite dimensional, one must actually have equality: $I=A$.

If $A$ is actually an algebra over a subfield of $L$, and you want to change fields to $K$, then look for "separable algebra" to see cases where things behave reasonably.

Comment: What about when $A$, $B$ and $C$ are just three finite dimensional central simple algebras over $k$. Does it follow $A \otimes B \approx A\otimes C$ $\rightarrow$ $B\approx C$?

Answer (score 3):

Consider $\mathbb{Q} \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Z}_n$. Since we have 
$$\frac{a}{b} \otimes k = \frac{a}{nb} \otimes nk = 0,$$
all the pure tensors vanish, so the tensor product does too. Comparing this with $\mathbb{Q} \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Z}$ shows that cancelation need not hold.

Comment: This is not an example, for $\mathbb Q\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb Z\not\cong\mathbb Q\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb Z_n$.

Answer (score 1):

I think I should point out the following in an answer.

As I said in the comment above, if you take a [divisible group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisible_group) $D$ and a finite abelian group $G$ then $D\otimes_\mathbb{Z} G=0$ for basically the same reason why the above user pointed out $\mathbb{Q}\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}_n=0$--of course neither of the factors is zero.

Moreover, it's clear that there are problems even with "nice" modules. For example, if you take something really nice, say some field $k$, then $k^m\otimes_k k^n\cong k^\ell\otimes_k k^j$ whenever $mn=\ell j$. That said, it's clear that since fields have the IBN property if we choose $m\ne \ell$ that $k^m\not\cong k^\ell$.

Comment: Wait, I thought dimensions multiplied with tensor products. Wouldn't it be whenever $mn=\ell j$?

Comment: Of course, I've editied it.

Comment: In your comment you had $G=S_5$ which doesn't make any sense. G needs to be abelian (or else it's not a $Z$-module!)